# java.lang.stringoutofboundsexception length=40, startRegion=21, regionLength=-15

Tags: java, android

I am new to Development and am now getting an out of bounds exception at the .substring

length=40, startRegion=21, regionLength=-15

the string is 40 characters and is being scanned in by a barcode reader. barcode is (01)90000055097706(3103)018130(10)24022402(30)00.

When scanned it appears as 0190000055097706310301813010240224023000

Please help.

Edited: Looking for the 018130 portion of the String. Thank you for pointing out the startIndex,endIndex. That was what I was missing, thought the syntax was startIndex,length.

Thanks again.

```
  String scannedAmount = scanAmount.getText().toString();
    if(scannedAmount.length() > 10)
    {
        scannedAmount = scannedAmount.substring(21, 6); // removes only the weight value in the string
        barcodeAmount = parseDouble(scannedAmount);
        barcodeAmount = barcodeAmount * conversion;//changes the weight from kg to lb
    } else if(scannedAmount.length()<=10) {
        barcodeAmount = parseDouble(scannedAmount);
    }
```

Comment: What you want to get from this string?

Comment: [Read the substring documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)): *Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.* <- Your startIndex is 21 and your endindex is 6. So you want a String that starts at position 21 but ends at 6 which would have a length of -15 as the error tells you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the syntax you're more familiar with is that of C#, which is `substring(startIndex, lengthOfSubstring)`, but in java the correct syntax is

```
substring(startIndex, endIndex)
```

where the `String` returned is the part of the string, starting from `startIndex` up until `endIndex` (not inclusive). So if you want six characters from your string starting at index `21` you should do,

```
scannedAmount = scannedAmount.substring(21, 27);
```

Comment: Nailed It! Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

scannedAmount = scannedAmount.substring(21, 6);

String substring end index is wrong. Below is jdk code.Your end index should be greater than begin index.

```
    <pre>int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex; 
          if (subLen < 0) {
             throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen); 
           }
      </pre>
```

Comment: edit your answer to insert the code in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

As listed on the oracle documentation website, this is how substring works:

> public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                  int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>  "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"
>  "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"
> ```

You need to pass the first index as the first argument and the second index as the second argument.

It is throwing the stringOutOfBoundsException because you are trying to index the string at the -15 index (6 - 21).

Change your code to look like this:

```
scannedAmount = scannedAmount.substring(6, 21);
```

and you will no longer get the exception from this line.

As to the functionality of the code, I cannot speak because you have not given any context for what should happen.